# How can I close the Matplotlib window without closing the whole program?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib to plot some values I get from an ADC, and the plotting itself works fine.

I will do 5 updates then stop the plotting of the values, but I can't close the figure window without stopping the whole program (using tkinter as well).

The best option in my mind is to being able to close the window on the little X in the corner or that it closes itself after the 5 updates, or anything else. The whole execution stops whenever I press the x, I still want the tkinter to run and being able to run it again without restarting the execution.

The code can be shown below, `voltage_converter` and `adc_1` is the other methods but they work fine. The tkinter menu I've created has a dedicated button to start `sensor()`.

```
def sensor():
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    lista = []
    current = []
    counter = 0
    while True: 
        lista.append(voltage_converter(adc_1()))
        for i in range(len(lista))
            plt.plot(lista[i])
            xcorr = [0,100]
            ycorr = [1.5, 1.5]
            plt.plot(xcorr, ycorr)
            plt.pause(1)
            plt.clf()
            counter = counter + 1
            time.sleep(7)
            lista.clear()
        if counter == 5:
            plt.clf()
            plt.close(fig)
            break
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.show(block=False)` ?

Comment: @MehdiSeifi Yes i've tried that one aswell. Figure just stops and whenever I press X button on the figure, the whole process crashes.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that `plt.ion()` means  [matplotlib.pyplot.ion()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html)?

have you tried telling the window to [close itself](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html)? At the moment you are just clearing the window with `plt.clf()` try:
`matplotlib.pyplot.close()`

Comment: I've tried to to use the close function, but at the moment it just stops after 5 updates and is still on the screen. Yes that assumtion is correct.

Comment: I've manage do be able to close it by simply adding a plt.pause() between plt.clf and plt.close(fig). If I set plt.pause(5) then I have 5 second to close it otherwise the same problem will occure, if I extend that time I'll have more time to close it, but the GUI button im using to start the plotting freezes during that time period. 
So im getting closer atleast...

Answer (score 0):

plt.close() should work here.

You can check [link](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html) for more options of close.